# Overflow interrupt firing only once

Tags: avr, interrupts, avr-gcc

I've run into an issue where, it appears, my interrupt only fires once, then simply refuses to fire again on my ATMega32U2. I have the following (stripped down) code:

```
void init(void) {
    DDRB = 0xff;
    PORTB = 0x00;

    TCCR0A = (1 << WGM01);
    // 1024 prescaler
    TCCR0B = ((1 << CS02) | (1 << CS00));
    // Interrupt every 4096 clocks
    OCR0A = 3;
    // Enable timer compare match interrupt
    TIMSK0 != (1 << OCIE0A);
}

ISR(TIMER0_COMPA_vect) {
    PORTB++;
}

int main(void) {
    init();

    sei();

    while(1);

    return 0;
}
```

When I plug an LED into each pin of `PORTB`, the first pin is high, while the rest are low. The most I can deduce from this is `PORTB` is incremented to `0x01` by the interrupt firing once, then left alone as the interrupt never fires again using the `TIMER0_COMPA_vect` vector.

**However**, if I replace the compare interrupt with an overflow interrupt (`TIMER0_OVF_vect`) and configure the registers differently, it works fine; `PORTB` cycles through 0 - 255 very quickly as I'd expect. This is my working code with the type of interrupt I don't want:

```
// Different timer config
void init(void) {
    DDRB = 0xff;
    PORTB = 0x00;

    TCCR0B |= (1 << CS01);

    // Enable timer 0 interrupt
    TIMSK0 |= (1 << TOIE0); 
}

// This time, it's an OVERFLOW vector, not a compare vector
ISR(TIMER0_OVF_vect) {
    PORTB++;
}

int main(void) {
    init();

    sei();

    while(1);

    return 0;
}
```

I've read what there is to read on Google, however the only fixes posted are logical errors that I don't think I have. I've read [this](http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&p=910567) forum post and had a look at the timer configuration registers, and they're exactly the same as my first example. I've also read [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/18514/handling-timer-overflow-and-compare-interrupts-in-atmega328-arduino), but that didn't help.

I've been following the tutorial on [this page](http://sites.google.com/site/artcfox/demystifying-the-tlc5940) (PDF) for the TLC5940 LED driver chip and am on Chapter 4 (refactoring code to use interrupts). Please note that I don't want to use the ready built library; I'm using this as a learning experience.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This may just be a typo in your post, but the line where you enable the Timer Compare interrupt says:

```
TIMSK0 != (1 << OCIE0A);
```

... when it should say ...

```
TIMSK0 |= (1 << OCIE0A);
```

It's subtle, but if that's what your code actually was, then you were comparing TIMSK0 to a constant rather than assigning to it (and therefore never actually enabling the interrupt).

On a sidenote, you can more concisely write:

```
TIMSK0 |= _BV(OCIE0A);
```

... instead of ..

```
TIMSK0 |= (1 << OCIE0A);
```

in avr-libc, if you're into that sort of thing :-).

Comment: whts that _BV?? I havent seen that..

Comment: But (1 << OCIE0A) is standard idiomatic C, and _BV(OCIE0A) uses an ugly unpronounceable macro that I've never seen before.  No thanks.

Comment: That should also be throwing a warning, though I'm not familiar with the compiler it's using. On my setup with GCC (4.5.1), it throws a "value computed is not used" warning.

Comment: @0xakhil - It's a macro  in avr-libc that gets the 'bit value' of the number.  For instance, `_BV(3)` turns into `0b0000 0100`, same as `( 1 << 3 )`.  It's pronounced "underscore Bee Vee".

Comment: @vicatcu Thanks for the tip. I'm ashamed I didn't see that myself, but now my interrupts work so all is well.

Comment: @JamWaffles no problem, glad I could help - don't underestimate the power of fresh eyes!

Comment: @markrages _BV is used throughout the avr-libc documentation. Using the macro gets rid of a lot of repeating yourself - there is no "information" in the "1 <<" part of the (1 << 3) idiom when your desire is simply to set a single bit at a given position. Less typing may result in fewer run time bugs. For example, it might prevent you from accidentally typing (1 < 3) when you meant (1 << 3)